# How publish Hootsuite on Google+ Pages stream?

Tags: google-plus, google-api-php-client

I want to achieve the same as ***Hootsuite***, publish a post in a PAGE STREAM. But I don't know even where to look for it. It looks like Hootsuite is using the API, because they prompt an open Auth authentication where the user selects and authorize what this APP can do with his data.

With the PHP client I've been able of posting in the user APP stream (different from the user main stream) using moments class, and get data from the user using plus class client, both from the PHP library available here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout

But I don't know how to write in a user's page. Does anyone knows or can point me where to go to, at least, publish on main Google+ page stream as Hootsuite? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google+ Pages API is currently available to a limited number of parters only, including HootSuite. You can request access to the API at https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup but there is no guarantee when, or even if, Google will approve your access.

Although you can use the HootSuite console to post messages to Google+ pages (see http://hootsuite.com/google+), it isn't clear if you can use the HootSuite API to do so.

Comment: Why is so hard to publish there! :_(
Thanks for your answer, I'll have to try something different... :P